# 110V power adaptor to 220V country

Tags: power, transformer, adapter

I have a question concerning a power adapter. 
I bought a weather station from US but I live in Sweden with   EU electric plug 220V.

The original power adaptor has the following spec.

Input : 120V AC 60HZ 6VA.
Output : 5V DC 100mA.

Which option is the best ?
Step down ? 
Can I use a 5V output voltage adaptor with my 220V input ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply.my intension was not to plug the 120V adaptor to my 220V plug, (won't feat anyway) i just thought instead of buying a step down adapter use a multipurpose adapter from my country with 220V input and 5V output

Comment: I stopped reading at the first word since you couldn't even be bothered to capitalize the word "I" and the first letter of the first sentence.  Whether you're too sloppy to care or too arrogant to bother, you get a -1 either way.  Go away until you can show some respect, and show that you are taking your own problem seriously.

Comment: Sorry sir, I never thought that a uncapitalize letter can harm so much someone, this was not my intension.

Comment: Not capitalising the __I__ in English is considered a sign of lack of self respect in some circles, that should bother you more than the formality that many believe the Stack Exchange site deserves.  Your spell checker should point them out to you even if your input device struggles though I see you have used capitals in most of the other places correctly.  Best to take care if you want the best value from the site.

Comment: @Kalle: It's more a sign of *"Eh, you're just a bunch of unimportant peons, so I can dump whatever slop on you I feel like, and you have to take it.  Your aggrevation in having to read my question isn't worth my time to bother following even universal and easy rules."*.  Or put another way *"I'm more important that all you dweebs!"*.  I see the OP still hasn't fixed it.  In fact, now some bystander did, so the OP can no longer redeem himself at all.  -1 and voting to close again if I could.

Comment: Of course i will go away Olin , when i first came here a have a simple electric problem and now you gave me another one. This is not a place to find a solution but get more problem, Get a life.. you spend so much time for a i or I letter

Comment: *"Of course i will go away"*.  Yet you are still here, and now deliberately using lower case "i".

Answer (score 4):

> Input : 120V AC 60HZ 6VA. Output : 5V DC 100mA

Get yourself a new adapter that works in your country and produces a regulated 5 volt output capable of supplying up to 100 mA - this is by far the cheapest option.